# Wi-Fi hotspot on MacBook with VPN

Tags: router, vpn, ethernet, wifi-configuration, hotspot

I have MacBook with macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6 using WiFi to connect to VPN server on Internet. Thus all my network traffic goes to the outside world through VPN.

How to configure MacBook network so MacBook could also share internet access for my Windows notebook?

My goal is to allow Windows notebook to use the same VPN server that my MacBook uses.
To share network in "System Preferences" on MacBook I do:

Select "Sharing."

In the left sidebar I choose "Internet Sharing."

In the "Share your connection from" dropdown menu I select VPN connection (e.g., Wi-Fi).

But in "To computers using" I have no Wi-Fi. It has Bluetooth PAN selected and Thunderbolt Bridge unselected and nothing more.

Is it possible to share it on the same interface, Wi-Fi in my case? I guess not.
So I need to connect MacBook to Wi-Fi router by ethernet cable. How to configure MacBook ethernet interface? And also Wi-Fi interface that I want to share?

Thanks!